# Did an apt-get upgrade openssl, now no email is received from other servers

Tags: email, server, dovecot

I just did an upgrade on an important server, and now, no email is received from other servers.

There is no error in `mail.log`, or any other log in that sense. It is as if no email even comes to the server from scratch. The server is not rejecting them. They don't even appear in the logs. They are not even bounced.

Upgrade performed:

```
apt-get upgrade openssl
```

It was after a bunch of `apt-get update`s, and service restarts. It was all fine that far, until I did the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Same here, updated openssl to patch potential DROWN attack vulnerability.  Must have been something extra in that patch that broke sendmail somehow :(